# How to get a Mocha test results report of a node applicaton in HTML

Tags: node.js, testing, report, mocha.js

When I run the following command on my windows command line `mocha --reporter spec > report.html` I get something that I cannot really use in my browser.

```
[0m[0m
[0m  Routes[0m
  [32m  √[0m[90m all GET routes should be bound to a function [0m
  [32m  √[0m[90m all POST routes should be bound to a function [0m
  [32m  √[0m[90m should have one for creating CU [0m

[0m  Database[0m
  [32m  √[0m[90m should be online, connectable and the right one [0m[31m(156ms)[0m

[0m  HTTPS API[0m
[0m    authentication[0m
    [32m  √[0m[90m is mandatory [0m[31m(1109ms)[0m
[0m    entity[0m
    [32m  √[0m[90m lookup should work [0m[31m(172ms)[0m
    [36m  - creation should work[0m

[0m  Website[0m
[0m    pages[0m
    [32m  √[0m[90m should contain quite a few of them [0m
    [32m  √[0m[90m all of them should have internal links to existing pages [0m


[92m [0m[32m 8 passing[0m[90m (2s)[0m
[36m [0m[36m 1 pending[0m
```

I would like some output as shown in this example  http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/example/tests.html which actually combines documentation together with the test result. Just the test result would be enough for me.

All searches that I do tell me about [code coverage](https://github.com/visionmedia/node-jscoverage) to get html, but I don't want that for now. I only need a html report out of Mocha (testing my node application) that I can view in my browser. Of course I can make something myself, but this seems trivial so I expect somebody to have created a [custom reporter](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/wiki/Third-party-reporters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer in [mocha-unfunk-reporter](https://github.com/Bartvds/mocha-unfunk-reporter). A mocha reporter without console funkyness and with html reporting capabilities.

Use as follows:

1. `npm install mocha-unfunk-reporter`
   *If you installed Mocha globally, you [need to install mocha-unfunk-reporter globally (add -g) as well](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/issues/541) otherwise you get a mocha invalid reporter error.*
2. In your test.js add options to set styling to `html` with css colors or css classes. Use style `css` for the latter: `process.env['mocha-unfunk-style'] = 'css';`
3. Run `mocha --reporter mocha-unfunk-reporter > unfunk.html`

You'll get:

```
<span class="mw-plain"></span>
<span class="mw-accent">-></span> running <span class="mw-accent">4 suites</span>

   <span class="mw-accent">Routes</span>
      <span class="mw-plain">all GET routes should be bound to a function.. </span><span class="mw-success">ok</span>
      <span class="mw-plain">all POST routes should be bound to a function.. </span><span class="mw-success">ok</span>
      <span class="mw-plain">should have one for creating CU.. </span><span class="mw-success">ok</span>

   <span class="mw-accent">Database</span>
      <span class="mw-plain">should be online, connectable and the right one.. </span><span class="mw-success">slow</span><span class="mw-error"> (125ms)</span>

   <span class="mw-accent">HTTPS API</span>
      <span class="mw-accent">authentication</span>
         <span class="mw-plain">is mandatory.. </span><span class="mw-success">medium</span><span class="mw-warning"> (47ms)</span>
      <span class="mw-accent">entity</span>
         <span class="mw-plain">lookup should work.. </span><span class="mw-success">ok</span>
         <span class="mw-plain">creation should work.. </span><span class="mw-warning">pending</span>

   <span class="mw-accent">Website</span>
      <span class="mw-accent">pages</span>
         <span class="mw-plain">should contain quite a few of them.. </span><span class="mw-success">ok</span>
         <span class="mw-plain">all of them should have internal links to existing pages.. </span><span class="mw-success">ok</span>

<span class="mw-plain">-> </span><span class="mw-success">passed 12</span> of <span class="mw-accent">12 tests</span>, left <span class="mw-warning">1 pending</span> (282ms)
```

Exactly what I needed!

Comment: cool, do you happen to know if there are any reporters for Mocha that write to a database?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [mochawesome](https://github.com/adamgruber/mochawesome). It's efficient and outputs both JSON and elegantly styled HTML reports.

Since most of us have mocha installed globally, it's best to install mochawesome globally as well.

```
npm install -g mochawesome
```

and then just run:

```
mocha --reporter mochawesome
```

from your test directory.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is using mochawesome: https://github.com/adamgruber/mochawesome

With the following script you can execute the tests (in the test/ folder) and view the results (in the report folder):

```
var Mocha = require('mocha'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),
    open = require('open');

var mocha = new Mocha({
    reporter: 'mochawesome',
    reporterOptions: {
      reportDir: 'report',
      reportName: 'report',
    }
});

var testDir = './tests'

fs.readdirSync(testDir).forEach(function(file){
    mocha.addFile(
        path.join(testDir, file)
    );
});

mocha.run(function(failures){

  open(__dirname + '/report/report.html', 'chrome');

  process.on('exit', function () {
    process.exit(failures);
  });
});
```